# Convert multiple .mp3 files (or single .m4a) into .m4b with ffmpeg and afconvert on macOS

Tags: macos, mp3, audiobook, m4a

I'm using macOS and have a set of .mp3 files that represent the chapters of an audiobook. I want to combine them into a single .m4b file.

How can I do this from command line without significantly increasing file size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Whelp, looks like [m4b-tool](https://github.com/sandreas/m4b-tool) is a great CLI tool for just this. I'm going to be switching over to use their solution instead of my custom ffmpeg/afconvert. I still use the python script to generate chapters.txt to be used with m4b-tool's merge script.

ORIGINAL:
After a lot of research, I found a CLI solution and wanted to share my findings here (if you're looking for an app to handle this for you, I've had really good luck with [Audiobook Binder](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/audiobook-binder/id413969927?mt=12), which can merge mp3s, m4as, and m4bs into a single m4b with very high efficiency).

The general idea of the process is to:

- Combine the separate mp3s into a single mp3
- Convert the combined mp3 into an m4a using afconvert (AFAIK mac-only) to reduce the amount of filesize increase from converting the mp3's to an m4a by utilizing the itunes plus commands ([stackexchange topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46076/what-are-the-afconvert-settings-for-the-itunes-plus-aac-encoding-setting); [apple docs](https://images.apple.com/ca/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/docs/mastered_for_itunes.pdf)) (my attempts at using ffmpeg for this part resulted in huge file size bloat or long processing times)

  - Note that there is still some file size bloat because the command I used to turn the caf > m4a drops the `-u pgcm 2` parameter because it resulted in errors (`Couldn't set audio converter property ('prop')`)
- Generate an FFMETADATA file ([more info](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata-1)) using a python script ([inspired by this](https://ikyle.me/blog/2020/add-mp4-chapters-ffmpeg)) to facilitate the conversion of an m4a to m4b and preserve chapters.
- Combine the m4a and FFMETADATA file into an m4b

Prereqs:

- Order your mp3 files in a directory for just that audiobook (ex. 00 - Chapter 1.mp3, 01 - Chapter 2.mp3, etc)
- Python3 (`brew install python` if you dont have it)
- FFMPEG (`brew install ffmpeg` if you don't have it)
- AFConvert (pre-installed on osx)

Steps:

1. Save the below python script to a file then execute it. Supply the audiobook directory that your mp3s are in. If you followed the ordering example above, the "enumeration separator" would be " - " (enter into the command without quotes)

```py
import re
import glob
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import os
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

chapterFileName = "chapters.txt"
metadataFileName = "FFMETADATAFILE"

def main():
   global chapterFileName
   global metadataFileName

   print("This script will help generate an FFMETADATA file to facilitate\nconverting an .m4a to a .m4b file")

   # scan given directory for file type
   directory=input('Directory (default pwd): ') or os.getcwd()
   print('   using: "' + directory + '"')
   chapterFileName = directory + "/chapters.txt";
   metadataFileName = directory + "/FFMETADATAFILE"

   skip = input('Skip chapter.txt creation? (default n): ') or 'n'
   if skip == 'y':
      createMetadataFile()
      return

   fileType=input('Input audio file type (default mp3): ') or 'mp3'
   print('   using: "' + fileType + '"')
   numberSeparator=input('Enumeration separator (symbol/phrase between enumeration and title): ') or ''
   print('   using: "' + (numberSeparator or '(blank)') + '"')
   if not directory or not fileType:
      print('Input missing - exiting')
      return

   fileNames = list()
   for file in glob.glob(directory + '/*.' + fileType):
      fileNames.append(file)
   fileNames.sort()

   rawChapters = list()
   currentTimestamp = 0 # in seconds
   for file in fileNames:
      audioLength = ''
      if fileType == 'mp3':
         audioLength = MP3(file).info.length
      else:
         audioLength = with_ffprobe(file)

      
      time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=currentTimestamp)) + '.000'

      title = os.path.splitext(file)[0].split('/')[-1]
      if numberSeparator != '':
         title = numberSeparator.join(title.split(numberSeparator)[1:])

      rawChapters.append(time + ' ' + title)
      currentTimestamp = int(currentTimestamp + audioLength)

   with open(chapterFileName, "w") as chaptersFile:
      for chapter in rawChapters:
         chaptersFile.write(chapter + "\n")

   input('File created at "' + chapterFileName + '". Review to make sure it looks right\n ("<timestamp> <title>"), then hit Enter to continue... ')
   createMetadataFile()

def createMetadataFile():
   global chapterFileName
   global metadataFileName

   # import chapters and create ffmetadatafile
   chapters = list()
   with open(chapterFileName, 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
         x = re.match(r"(\d*):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{3}) (.*)", line)
         hrs = int(x.group(1))
         mins = int(x.group(2))
         secs = int(x.group(3))
         title = x.group(5)

         minutes = (hrs * 60) + mins
         seconds = secs + (minutes * 60)
         timestamp = (seconds * 1000)
         chap = {
            "title": title,
            "startTime": timestamp
         }
         chapters.append(chap)

   text = ";FFMETADATA1\n"
   for i in range(len(chapters)-1):
      chap = chapters[i]
      title = chap['title']
      start = chap['startTime']
      end = chapters[i+1]['startTime']-1
      text += f"[CHAPTER]\nTIMEBASE=1/1000\nSTART={start}\nEND={end}\ntitle={title}\n"

   with open(metadataFileName, "w") as myfile:
       myfile.write(text)
   
   print('Created metadata file at "' + metadataFileName + '"')
   removeChapters = input('Remove chapter.txt? (default n): ') or 'n'
   if removeChapters == 'y':
      os.remove(chapterFileName)


def with_ffprobe(filename):
    import subprocess, json

    result = subprocess.check_output(
            f'ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v:0 -of json "{filename}"',
            shell=True).decode()
    fields = json.loads(result)['streams'][0]
    return float(fields['duration'])

main()
```

2. Open Terminal to the directory of your mp3s and FFMETADATA file and execute the following command:

```sh
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.mp3; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.mp3 && \
  afconvert output.mp3 intermediate.caf -d 0 -f caff --soundcheck-generate -v && \
  afconvert intermediate.caf -d aac -f m4af --soundcheck-read -b 256000 -q 127 -s 2 output.m4a -v && \
  ffmpeg -i output.m4a -i FFMETADATAFILE -map_metadata 1 -codec copy output.m4b && \
  rm output.mp3 output.m4a FFMETADATAFILE intermediate.caf
```

This is a joined command that will (you can split it up at the "&&"s and run separately if you want):
(1) combine the mp3's into a single mp3 called "output.mp3";
(2) convert the combined mp3 into an intermediate caff file;
(3) convert the caff file into an m4a;
(4) combine the m4a and FFMETADATAFILE into an m4b;
(5) clean up the files used and generated by this command

If the file bloat is too much from afconvert, you can also move combined mp3 (output.mp3) into Music/iTunes and convert to aac from there (if so, don't need scripts 2 & 3 here), but its a lot slower and may not yield significant improvements.

3. You now have an m4b file (output.m4b) to use! I like to open the file in the freeware [Kid3](https://kid3.kde.org) tag editor and add the following fields:

   - Title: title of audiobook
   - Author
   - Album: title of audiobook
   - Comment: audiobook description
   - Genre: "Audiobook"
   - Date: Year of recording or book published
   - Cover

From here, you can add the m4b to your audiobooks app of choice or store it in your calibre library